# Changing part of a document using CouchDB PUT

Tags: couchdb

Reading the documentation (and playing around with the software), it looks like a PUT command will replace the entire existing document (create a new revision which includes only what was sent in PUT command). Is there a way to update part of a document?

For example, let's say a POST command creates a document with the following JSON object:

```
{"name" : "Chuck"}
```

Then a PUT command on the same document id adds:

```
{"lastname" : "Norris"}
```

Is there a way to get CouchDB to return the combination of the two revisions, as opposed to just the latest update? Otherwise any change to a document will require retrieving the complete document, and sending the complete (updated) document back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try looking into [Document Update Handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers): when an update handler is `PUT` from your application, the corresponding JavaScript function will be called with the data your application sent *and the existing document on the server*, which lets it merge the two pieces of data appropriately.

Comment: While the above answer gives a general overview, this page gives specifics (and examples!) of how to do what the OP requested: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Partial_Updates

Comment: Consider updating links to updated resources, the entire wiki is deprecated (it is mentioned on their Frontpage too).